# React testing with Jest and React Testing Library not renderin text displayed on the webpage

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a NextJS app that I am using Jest and React Testing Library to test.  I have a card component that is passed data (id, image url, text, and name) that is rendered on the card.  This works correctly on the webpage.  When I run the test, the test cannot find any text on the page.

Here is the component:

```
import React from "react";

import Image from "next/image";

import styles from "./testCard.module.css";

export default function TestCard(data) {
  const card = data.data;

  return (
    <>
      <div className={styles.cardContainer}>
        <div className={styles.cardTop}>
          <div className={styles.cardImg}>
            <Image
              src={card.imgUrl}
              alt=""
              height={150}
              width={150}
              loading="lazy"
              className={styles.circular}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.cardBottom}>
          <div className={styles.cardText}>
            <p>&quot;{card.text}&quot;</p>
          </div>
          <div className={styles.cardName}>
            <p>-{card.name}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Here is the test file:

```
import React from "react";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";

import TestCard from "./testCard";

import { testimonialMock } from "../../__mocks__/next/testimonialMock";

describe("TestCard Component", () => {
  it("renders the component", () => {
    render(<TestCard data={testimonialMock} />);
  });
  it("renders the component unchanged", () => {
    const { containter } = render(<TestCard data={testimonialMock} />);
    expect(containter).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
  it("renders the passed in data", () => {
    render(<TestCard data={testimonialMock} />);
    screen.getByRole('p', {name: /test text/i});    
  });
});
```

And here is the testimonialMock.js file:

```
export const testimonialMock = [
  {
    id: 0,
    imgUrl: "/img/mock.png",
    text: "test text",
    name: "test name",
  },
];
```

Here is the result I am getting:

```
TestCard Component
    ✓ renders the component (12 ms)
    ✓ renders the component unchanged (5 ms)
    ✕ renders the passed in data (15 ms)

  ● TestCard Component › renders the passed in data

    TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: test text. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.

    Ignored nodes: comments, script, style
    <body>
      <div>
        <div
          class="cardContainer"
        >
          <div
            class="cardTop"
          >
            <div
              class="cardImg"
            />
          </div>
          <div
            class="cardBottom"
          >
            <div
              class="cardText"
            >
              <p>
                "
                "
              </p>
            </div>
            <div
              class="cardName"
            >
              <p>
                -
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>

      17 |   it("renders the passed in data", () => {
      18 |     render(<TestCard data={testimonialMock} />);
    > 19 |     expect(screen.getByText("test text")).toBeInTheDocument();
         |                   ^
      20 |   });
      21 | });
      22 |

      at Object.getElementError (node_modules/.pnpm/@testing-library+dom@8.19.0/node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/config.js:40:19)
      at node_modules/.pnpm/@testing-library+dom@8.19.0/node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:90:38
      at node_modules/.pnpm/@testing-library+dom@8.19.0/node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:62:17
      at node_modules/.pnpm/@testing-library+dom@8.19.0/node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:111:19
      at Object.getByText (components/testCard/testCard.test.js:19:19)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 2 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   1 passed, 1 total
Time:        0.725 s, estimated 1 s
Ran all test suites matching /testCard.test.js/i.
```

I have tried using different forms of passing in the data and different queries, all to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a single object as the mock (*no `data` prop inside it*), but fix the confusing use of `data` instead of `props` for the component arguments.

Then use the `getByText` instead of the `getByRole`

so

```
export default function TestCard(props) {
  const card = props.data;
  ....
}
```

then in your mock file

```
export const testimonialMock = {
    id: 0,
    imgUrl: "/img/mock.png",
    text: "test text",
    name: "test name",
  };
```

and finally in the test

```
 screen.getByText(/test text/i);
```

Comment: Thank you, the data prop was the problem.  Greatly appreciated, Gabriele.